# Unable to launch Flutter Project in Chrome

Tags: windows, xcode, firebase, flutter, dart

I am writing my Flutter app in xCode on a Laptop running Windows 10.  I transferred the project 1 month ago from my Desktop that is also running windows 10.

When I run the project through an android emulator the app works perfectly.  When I run the app through google Chrome the google chrome window launches and even has flutter startup animations, but the page then goes completely blank with a white backdrop.  When the app is launched it highlights the following line back on xCode in the web_entrypoint.dart file.

```
await ui.webOnlyInitializerPlatform();
```

The flutter doctor is not giving any error, and the debug console is not giving an error either.  The last line on the debug console is "Connecting to VM service at ...

I tried using flutter build web in the terminal, but that did not resolve the issue.
The only thing I can think this might be tied to is my app's connection with Firebase.  I have successfully configured the app to work with android and ios, but I'm not sure what needs to be done if anything on the web side of things.  Any idea on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved the issue by recreating the app and reconfiguring my Firebase initialization code.

in main.dart

```
void main() {
  // USED FOR FIREBASE FLUTTER WEB
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

in main.dart under the MyApp class

```
    // USED FOR FIREBASE FLUTTER WEB
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
```

in main.dart under Widget build

```
// USED FOR FIREBASE FLUTTER WEB
  home: FutureBuilder(
    future: _initialization,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        print("Error");
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        return Nav();
      }
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
```

in index.html

```
    <!--  USED FOR FIREBASE FLUTTER WEB  -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>-->
  <script>

    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "***",
      authDomain: "***",
      projectId: "***",
      storageBucket: "***",
      messagingSenderId: "***",
      appId: "***",
      measurementId: "***"
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
```

You can get the code specific to your project from your firebase console.  I also had to remove some const identifiers from the code as they gave an error.  This reworking of my code now allows me to connect to firebase without error through web browsers like chrome.
This is a video that helped me through the error.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0cFOUJJcGQ&t